# Blender extrude function issue

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to extrude a simple cylinder, but when I do, it seems like it's trying to make a copy of the item and then move it along an axis.

[image]

All I want to do is make the cylinder longer, but I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Select only one circular edge loop - top or bottom one, not whole mesh.

Comment: Select the cylinder in Object mode, then goto Edit mode, select only the top row of vertices (dots) and press G, then Z, move the cursor up to stretch the cylinder.  To Extrude, select the top row of verticies, press E then Z then Space to terminate the extrude, move the cursor (mouse) up to the desired height.  You won't need to press any mouse button to drag the new vertices.  Extrude will add an extra row of vertices to the cylinder.